# Integrating OpenCV into Swift in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opencv

I was following this blog: https://saitoxu.io/2016/11/06/how-to-use-opencv-in-swift.html , and was trying to integrate openCV into swift. I am getting a Mach-O Apple Linker Error and have tried almost everything and nothing seems to work (Yes, I'm using the workspace). I have also tried playing around with some of the build settings, restarting xcode and cleaning and then rebuilding, and a few other things. My error message is "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
" Let me know if you know how this can be solved, any suggestions may be helpful! Here are some screenshots of my code and important files:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShabT.png)[OpenCV code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLKev.png)[Header File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFBQ9.png)[Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrzTQ.png)[More Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rKWf.png)

I have tried a few different ways of integrating openCV as well like https://medium.com/@borisohayon/ios-opencv-and-swift-1ee3e3a5735b which has directly importing the framework instead of cocoa pods and I still get some errors. So let me know if there other ways to cleanly integrate. Thank you so much!

Comment: The Bridging header is for implementing the header files, not declarations from that header files.

Comment: Try to read that tutorials at least 5 times in a row and you will get this. They don't lie, believe me ;)